# Capistrano 3 / SSHKit.config.umask not working

Tags: capistrano3, sshkit

I'm trying to run a test command with `SSHKit.config.umask` configured:

deploy.rb:

```rb
SSHKit.config.umask = '777'
```

deploy.rake

```rb
namespace :deploy do
  task :test do
    on roles :web do
      execute('touch ~/hello.txt')
    end
  end
end
```

I expect `hello.txt` to be configures with no permissions, but I see:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy    0 Apr  9 15:40 hello.txt`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the following syntax to that the command was executed via the [command map](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map):

```rb
execute(:touch, '~/hello.txt')
```

Now the permissions are correct:

`---------- 1 deploy deploy    0 Apr  9 15:44 hello.txt`